# Good documentation about Shibboleth and SAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-sign-on, saml, shibboleth

Where can I find useful documentation about using Shibboleth and SAML for SSO besides the Shibboleth Wiki pages, preferably for Ruby applications? Ruby-specific documentation for Shibboleth seems to be very sparse. Does anyone know good resources, tutorials or HowTos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only useful documentation I found is the official documentation from the creators of Shibboleth and SAML themselves. This seems to be a good technical overview about SAML 2 in general from the standards organization OASIS: [Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0 Technical Overview](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf). One can also read the [complete SAML specifications](http://saml.xml.org/saml-specifications), but I doubt this will be a good start. The only authorative source for Shibboleth seems to be the [Shibboleth Wiki](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Home) itself.

Answer (score 0):

These links will help you.

- http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?s=saml
- https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUsrManJavaInstall

Comment: I asked for **good** resources, tutorials, or HowTos. SAML is a complicated issue, if wonder if there are any **good and simple** explanations at all for this convoluted topic.